# ng-table sorting not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, ngtable

I have created an application using ng-table, the application is working fine which had generated table using ng-table. The problem which i am facing is that the table sorting is not working. My code is as given below

[**Working Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gnFWDx3YNryP7lJza76H?p=preview)

**html**

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in myValues">
            <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'">
                {{user.name}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Age'" sortable="'age'">
                {{user.age}}
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable']).
controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $filter, ngTableParams) {
    $scope.myValues = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34}, 
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34}];

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        sorting: {
            name: 'asc'     
        }
    }, {
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            $defer.resolve($filter('orderBy')($scope.myValues, params.orderBy()));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$defer.resolve($filter('orderBy')($scope.myValues, params.orderBy()));
```

will create a new sorted array but will not change `$scope.myValues`.

So either, you set `$scope.myValues` to the sorted array each time:

```
$scope.myValues = $filter('orderBy')($scope.myValues, params.orderBy());
$defer.resolve($scope.myValues);
```

Or use `$data` in `ng-repeat`instead of `myValues`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
```

Comment: I think that the use of $data to fetch items is not obviously a solution to update the array data. I use this, and I still have to do a manual filter into my getData function in order to see my sort applied. thx for the tip

Answer (score 5):

In your HTML you need to update the myValues to be $data.

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/adb4jW?p=preview)

Comment: so if there are two tables then how will i tell which data to be taken

Answer (score 3):

You're writing to `$scope.myValues`, and using that in the `ng-repeat` directive - but you're sorting the data only in `getData()` on the table params object.

`getData()` doesn't ever change `$scope.myValues`, it only uses it to return a sorted array. What you really want to do is:

- Don't make the full dataset available on the scope, but store it in a variable inside the controller:

`var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50}, ...]`

`$defer.resolve($filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()));`

- Use `$data` inside the HTML code, because this is what accesses `getData()`:

`<tr ng-repeat="user in $data">`