# ng-table not showing data from http get

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ngtable

I'm trying to make a ng-table with ajax data with angularjs and rails.
I saw that the http get was successfully get the data but for some reason I coun't append it into my table, it always show no records. 
Here is my code. 
Thank you

```js
(function(){
  var app = angular.module("apTags", ["ngTable"]);

  app.controller("apTagsController", function($scope, $timeout, $http, ngTableParams){
    $http.get('/owners/ap_tags/ap_tags_json.json')
    .success(function(data, status) {
      $scope.tags = data;

      $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
          page: 1,            // show first page
          count: 10,           // count per page
          sorting: {name:'asc'}
      }, {
          total: $scope.tags.length, // length of data
          getData: function($defer, params) {
             var orderedData = $scope.tags;
            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            
          }
      });
    });
  });
})();
```

```html
<div class="container" ng-app="apTags">
  <div ng-controller="apTagsController as list">
    <p><strong>Page:</strong> {{tableParams.page()}}</p>
    <p><strong>Count per page:</strong> {{tableParams.count()}}</p>
    <p>Filter: <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="filter.$" /></p>
    <table ng-table="tableParams" id="table_tags" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Tag</th>
          <th>Share</th>
          <th>Direct Product Count</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="tag in list.tags">
          <td >{{tag.name}}</td>
          <td >{{tag.share}}%</td>
          <td ></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my rails controller

```html
class Owners::ApTagsController < WlApplicationController
  respond_to :json, only: [:ap_tags_json]
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        @tags = ApTag.all
        render :json => @tags.map(&:attributes)
      end
      format.html
    end
  end

  def ap_tags_json
    data = ApTag.all
    respond_with(data) do |format|
      format.json { render :json => data.map(&:attributes).as_json }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the success function of your HTTP GET request, you set the response data to `$scope.tags`.

Then in your HTML, when you iterate over it, you have `ng-repeat="tag in list.tags`.  Either attach `tags` to the `list` object (`$scope.list = {}; $scope.list.tags = data;`).

Or, iterate over the right data in your HTML: `ng-repeat="tag in tags"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still doesn't work for me. I defined my controller <div ng-controller="apTagsController as list"> that's why in ng-repeat I called "tag in list.tags"

Answer (score 0):

When using ng-table you should iterate over $data instead of list.tags.   More details are covered by this question: [ng-table sorting not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237405/ng-table-sorting-not-working)